Incentivize chess players not to play for a draw
Problem:
The current state of professional chess  yield a lot of drawn games. Let's assume that in 30% of games white wins, 50% of games are drawn and in 20% of games, black wins. When white or black win, they get 1 point. if game is drawn, players gets 0.5 points if white or black lose, they get 0 points. How can encourage the chess players to NOT play for draws by changing the scoring system.
Attempt:
Can we express the winning rate per color with the following expression:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2\\
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0.5\\
0.0
\end{pmatrix}$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
0.8\\
0.7
\end{pmatrix}$
If yes, would the following equation result a just scoring system for wining winning, drawing, losing respectfully x,y,z for row 1- white, row 2 black
$\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2\\
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$
however the 2x3 matrix is not really invertible,
If we try to provide some pseudo invert matrix:
>>> A = np.array([[0.3, 0.5, 0.2], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]])  # 2x3 matrix
>>> A
array([[0.3, 0.5, 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]])
>>> pseudo_inverse = np.linalg.pinv(A)
>>> pseudo_inverse
array([[ 5.33333333, -4.66666667],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.66666667],
       [-4.66666667,  5.33333333]])

and we have B as:
>>> B
array([[1],
       [1]])

>>> np.matmul(pseudo_inverse, B)
array([[0.66666667],
       [1.33333333],
       [0.66666667]])

is our result. Let us verify:
>>> np.matmul(A, result)
array([[1.],
       [1.]])

Question:
This does solve  my equation, but does not seem like a solution to my problem. How can we change the scoring system so that we incentivize the players to NOT play for a draw in a just manner?
Edit:
Could we interpret this problem as an optimization problem as such:
$$maxf(..)=x-w-b-z$$
$$0.3x+0.5w+0.2z=1$$
$$0.2x+0.5b+0.3z=1$$
$$x>b>w>z\geq 0$$

I don't think that changing the scoring system will solve this "problem"

I'm not sure what you're going for here.  Your question is "How can we change the scoring system so that we incentivize the players to NOT play for a draw in a just manner?"  It seems obvious to me that if we reduce the score for a draw from $\frac12$ point for each player to $0$ points for each player, the players will be incentivized to not play for a draw, because a draw is now as bad as a loss. Is this a "just manner"? I don't know because you didn't say what you would consider "just". Do you object to this saying that it gives White an even greater advantage over Black?

In some sports the scoring is $3$ point for a win, $1$ for a tie, $0$ for loosing. That obviously encourage to go for the win. You can even give $10$ points for a win, $1$ for a tie, $0$ for a loose. That works even better. The problem would be if you consider that to be "fair". But that would be a subjective problem, so I think you need to specify your problem better.

In a 1 v 1 game, I don't see any way around this challenge; every win is another's loss, and vice versa. With multiple players, one can incentivize scoring in such a way that draws are reduced when playing noncompetitive match-ups, because game theory would encourage the taking of risks.

There's a Chess Stack Exchange! And your question is a good one - the drawish nature of chess at the absolute top level has been discussed extensively. One of the proposed solutions is "no-castling chess" which is just standard chess, but the kings aren't allowed to castle. This reduces draw frequency - it typically leads to more attacking chances for both sides, and therefore a lower draw probability. There's also a format that is often used in tiebreakers, armageddon, in which white has a time advantage, but draws are wins for black.

@Sine of the Time I Assume it will, because it's hard to play for a win, but it's rewarding enough to play for a draw

@NotQuiteHuman I disagree, because if we play armwrestle, we should be having a similar opportunity, but in competitive chess, white always has some kind of an edge

@jjagmath I am not sure, but I think my result $\begin{pmatrix}
0.8\
0.7
\end{pmatrix}$  says that white has a winning rate. if we have the rate to be $\begin{pmatrix}
1\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ would be a fair scoring system, where both colors would have the same winning rates

@ZubinMukerjee I am aware of all those things, I have checked the chess stack exchange, but I think this is a better spot for this question. I don't like the armagedon, there is a tournament Norwar chess, in which draw results in armagedon and it does make it interesting, but I don't think it's just. I think there can be a scoring systems that if a player A plays 100 games with white and player B plays 100 games with black, at the end they would have a similar score. Currently, player A will certainly  have more points than player B

One must acknowledge that chess is different from other sports. At higher level, it's normal that there are more draws; this follows from the fact that top players have access to the same tools and, with the use of computers it's more difficult to find novelties. Changing rules (no castling) or the score system, will simply change the nature of this game.

There are two separate problems that it looks like you're attempting to solve simultaneously:

The white player wins significantly more often than black.
Draws are too common.

So what would be desirable would be a scoring system where the expected value for each player is equal, and where there is a disincentive to draw.
The system you've proposed would be: Award 4/3 points to both players for a draw and 2/3 points if the game is not a draw. Obviously, that's not going to work!
So let's break down the situation: Let $x$ be the award for winning a game, $z$ the award for losing, and $y$ for a draw. We clearly would like to have $x>y>z$. Then, to solve problem 1. we would like to have:\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(\text{score playing white}) &=&\mathbb{E}(\text{score playing black})\\
0.3x+0.5y+0.2z&=&0.2x+0.5y+0.3z\\
0.1 x&=&0.1z 
\end{eqnarray}
But obviously, we don't want $x=z$, that makes no sense! We could solve this by making the scores asymmetric: suppose that, if it's a draw, white gets $w$ points while black gets $b$. Then, to balance the game, we'll need:\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(\text{score playing white}) &=&\mathbb{E}(\text{score playing black})\\
0.3x+0.5w+0.2z&=&0.2x+0.5b+0.3z\\
0.1 (x-z)&=&0.5(b-w)\\
x-z&=&5(b-w)
\end{eqnarray}
So far so good! Next, we want to solve problem 2: draws are too common. To incentivize white to play for the win, we should set $x,w,z$ such that, when the position would give you a 50:50 odds of winning or losing if played out, it would be better to play for a win than for a draw. Equivalently:$$
0.5x+0.5z > w
$$
Similarly, to incentivize black to play for the win, we want to have $$
0.5x+0.5z>b
$$
Note that if $(x,z,b,w)$ satisfies all these conditions, we can shift and rescale by arbitrary constants and still preserve the desire relations between them. So, let's suppose arbitrarily that $z=0$ and $x=10$. Then we want $(z,b,w)$ to satisfy\begin{eqnarray}
10&=&5(b-w)\\
5&>&b\\
5&>&w
\end{eqnarray}
There's lots of possible systems, the easiest would be to set $b=3.5$ and $w=1.5$. Then, out scoring system is as follows: The winning player gets 10 points while the losing player gets 0. If the game is a draw, black scores 3.5 and white scores 1.5. Then, because of the asymmetry, white and black have the same expected score. But both players are incentivized to play for a win if the situation on the board looks like a toss-up.
This is just one suggestion. You can play with the numbers a bit to see if you can find a better one. One substantial issue is that, if players were incentivized not to draw, they would play differently, which would skew the percentages and potentially not in a balanced way.

Yes, this looks very nice! I proposed an edit to generalize this as an optimization problem. I wonder if it's correct. Hasn't someone thought of a  generalized scoring system for imbalanced games

In a 1 v 1 game, the players are incentivized just as much to prevent the other player from winning (which in your setup gives the other player 10 points). I don't believe there is a way to disincentivize draws in this scenario. In a multiplayer tournament this setup may reduce draws to a small degree.

@NotQuiteHuman Sure, that's true. But in real games people often agree to a draw not because there's no play left but because the game reaches a point where it is not worth the effort of playing for a win anymore. If the cost of not playing for a win in that scenario is greater, then draws will indeed be disincentivized.
